# LabVIEW initialize array of strings

Tags: arrays, string, labview

I am quite new to LabVIEW and struggling with some topics: I have create an array and dragged a string constant into the array. The result is I have a 1 dimensional array for string constants. Now I want to fill this array with some string I use in different locations of my VI.

How can I initialize the values in the string array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can type your values into the string constant.
2. You can write a program to output an array into an indicator, run the VI and then convert the indicator to a constant.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Build Array, found on the Array pallet is probably the most straightforward way to create an array of constant values.

Build array can also be used to add elements to the end of an existing array. You can wire your existing array to the first input of build array and wire string constants to the other inputs. If this causes a broken wire, right click on the Build Array and make sure the concatenate property is set properly.

Build array is a growable function. This is true of several of the array functions. If you hover your mouse over the lower edge of build array, the mouse cursor will change to a double headed arrow. Left click and then drag down or up to get the number of inputs you need.